# Android: Get a DAO in a ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

What is the best way to get a Android Room DAO in a ViewModel?

Based on the [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html#classes) example I wrote this ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel(myDao: MyDao) : ViewModel() {

    val data = myDao.get().create(
            /* initial load position */ 0,
            PagedList.Config.Builder()
                    .setPageSize(50)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(50)
                    .build())
}
```

I then try to get an instance

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Trying to run this I get an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{....MyActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ...MyViewModel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ...MyViewModel
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:145)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders$DefaultFactory.create(ViewModelProviders.java:158)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:128)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:96)
    ...
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<...MyViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
```

From the [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html#classes) example it is not apparent how the view model gets a copy of the DAO, and apparently it fails. Question is if I have missed something, or is the example incomplete?

Googling the exception I find suggestions to use a ViewModelProvider.Factory, only the example did not use this. In the example code the view model looks like this:

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public final LiveData<PagedList<User>> usersList;
    public MyViewModel(UserDao userDao) {
        usersList = userDao.usersByLastName().create(
                /* initial load position */ 0,
                new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                        .setPageSize(50)
                        .setPrefetchDistance(50)
                        .build());
    }
}
```

And is retreived like this

```
MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

My dependencies

```
def roomVersion = "1.0.0"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"
implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3"
```

Comment: @pskink Not sure it makes a difference if the DAO is never created, but it looks like this: `@Query("SELECT * FROM MyEntity") fun get(): LivePagedListProvider<Int, MyEntity>`. I can still initiate the DAO in another part of the app to insert entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [paging example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingSample/app/src/main/java/paging/android/example/com/pagingsample) by google. Based on that I wrote this view model (see [CheeseViewModel](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PagingSample/app/src/main/java/paging/android/example/com/pagingsample/CheeseViewModel.kt)):

```
class MyViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    val data = MyDatabase.get(app).dao.get().create(
            /* initial load position */ 0,
            PagedList.Config.Builder()
                    .setPageSize(50)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(50)
                    .build())
}
```

And I added this to my DB class (see [CheeseDb](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PagingSample/app/src/main/java/paging/android/example/com/pagingsample/CheeseDb.kt)):

```
companion object {

    // Google example noted that this might not be the best
    // solution and to use a dependency injection framework instead.

    private var instance: MyDatabase? = null

    @Synchronized
    fun get(context: Context): MyDatabase {
        return instance ?: Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                MyDatabase::class.java, "myDB")
                .build()
                .also { instance = it }
    }
}
```

So that answers the question on how to get a DAO instance in a view model. Regarding the other question, I guess that the [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html#classes) example was incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have parameterized constructor in your ViewModel class for that you need to pass parameter while initializing ViewModel.

Below is the code in java

```
public class UserInfoViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    LiveData<PagedList<UserInfo>> usersForList;
    private PersonRepository personRepository;  

    public UserInfoViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        personRepository = new PersonRepository(application);
    }  

    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

        @NonNull
        private final Application mApplication;

        public Factory(@NonNull Application application) {
            mApplication = application;
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new UserInfoViewModel(mApplication);
        }
    }

    public void init() {

            usersForList = personRepository.getAllPersonsForList().create(0,
                    new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                            .setPageSize(50)
                            .setPrefetchDistance(10)
                            .build());

    }
}
```

In your Activity, you can access the ViewModel as shown in below code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UserInfoViewModel.Factory factory = new UserInfoViewModel.Factory(
                this.getApplication());
        userInfoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory)
                .get(UserInfoViewModel.class);
        userInfoViewModel.init();
    }
```

Here is my repository object in repository using DAO object as shown in below code

**PersonRepository.java**

```
public class PersonRepository {

    private final ChatListDAO personDAO;

    public PersonRepository(Context context) {
        personDAO = DatabaseCreator.getChatDatabase(context).ChatDatabase();
    }
}
```

**DAO.java class**

```
@Dao
public interface DAO{

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
     long insertPerson(UserInfo person);

    @Update
     void updatePerson(UserInfo person);

    @Delete
     void deletePerson(UserInfo person);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person")
     LiveData<List<UserInfo>> getAllPersons();

    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM person")
     LiveData<Integer> getAllPersonsCount();


    @Query("SELECT * FROM person where number = :mobileIn")
     LiveData<UserInfo> getPersonByMobile(String mobileIn);


    @Query("SELECT * FROM person")
    public abstract LivePagedListProvider<Integer,UserInfo> getUsersForList();
}
```

Comment: You should not need a factory to pass `application` to an [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel.html), you get that for free, like in [CheeseViewModel](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PagingSample/app/src/main/java/paging/android/example/com/pagingsample/CheeseViewModel.kt)